# How to get files from "Documents" in my app to my Mac

Tags: iphone, ios4

My app saves some files into its documents directory.

I want to get these files back to my computer. How may I do that? I heard I can use iPhone Organizer for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iTunes (maybe you can use organizer as well). Select the app you want to get documents from and there you should be able to locate the documents.

Comment: i had to add "Application supports iTunes file sharing" to my app.plist file, but it works. Thanks!